# Can I code in Arduino depending up on LED status?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have to count the blinkings of an LED. For that

```
IF (LED = ON)
{
    COUNT=COUNT++
}
Else
{   
}
```

Can I code like this algorithm? In Arduino is it possible?

Comment: Instead of controling led through arduino ,can we code in  arduino to read the led status as input???? Like the above theme???

Comment: In C (the language used to program Arduinos) tests require two equal signs.  Using one equal sign will assign the variable on the left side of the equal sign the value on the right side of the equal sign.  Also, when incrementing a variable you only need the two plus signs following the variable.  So "COUNT=COUNT++" should likely be "COUNT++".

Comment: `if( digitalRead(ledPin)==HIGH )...`?

Comment: it is a duplicate ... posted by the same person ... evidently the OP asks questions, but does not read the answers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make an arduino detect and count LED blinking. You will need some kind of light sensor, such as a [photodiode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode) or [photoresistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoresistor).

Also, you would need to code in C++, and the example pseudo-code you presented is not C or C++.

As you proceed with your project, you may ask more questions here, of a more specific nature. As it stands, your question is very broad.

Comment: Oh really thanks sir... Can I simply connect the led to digital pins of arduino ??

Comment: You have already asked that before.

Comment: @rajiravi You will have to work out what the circuit is you are connecting to before you can know if it is possible to connect to it. Suffice it to say, probably no, *you* cannot connect directly to it. Someone with more knowledge probably can, but if you are asking, the answer is going to be no. Especially if it involves dismantling power company owned and installed and certified equipment.